# Is there a way to create a type in typescript by iterating over an array of generics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using a third-party library *(react-navigation)* that provides a Utility Type to merge two types together. When I want to merge more than two types, I have to keep nesting the Utility to obtain the desired merged type.

I would like to avoid this nesting (or rather hide it) in a custom Utility Type that would take as many types as a Generic and merge everything. I could come up with the following implementation for that:

```js
type MultipleCompositeItem<Items extends (LibItem | never)[] = []> =
  Items[0] extends LibItem
    ? LibCompositeItem<
        GlobalItem,
        Items[1] extends LibItem
          ? LibCompositeItem<
              Items[0],
              Items[2] extends LibItem
                ? LibCompositeItem<
                    Items[1],
                    Items[3] extends LibItem
                      ? LibCompositeItem<Items[2], Items[3]>
                      : Items[2]
                  >
                : Items[1]
            >
          : Items[0]
      >
    : GlobalItem;
```

But this is really only taking 4 `LibItem`s and if I want it to take more, I have to keep adding the conditionals.

Here's a full example of its usage compared to using just the utility provided by the library:

```js
// I can't change these types
type LibItem = { genericProp: string };
type LibCompositeItem<A extends LibItem, B extends LibItem> = A & B; // This is way more complex in the real implementation

type GlobalItem = { globalProp: string } & LibItem;
type ItemA = { propA: string } & LibItem;
type ItemB = { propB: string } & LibItem;
type ItemC = { propC: string } & LibItem;
type ItemD = { propD: string } & LibItem;

type MultipleCompositeItem<Items extends (LibItem | never)[] = []> =
  Items[0] extends LibItem
    ? LibCompositeItem<
        GlobalItem,
        Items[1] extends LibItem
          ? LibCompositeItem<
              Items[0],
              Items[2] extends LibItem
                ? LibCompositeItem<
                    Items[1],
                    Items[3] extends LibItem
                      ? LibCompositeItem<Items[2], Items[3]>
                      : Items[2]
                  >
                : Items[1]
            >
          : Items[0]
      >
    : GlobalItem;

// This is how I have to merge in each component that uses Items
type MergedItems = LibCompositeItem<
  LibCompositeItem<GlobalItem, ItemA>,
  LibCompositeItem<ItemB, LibCompositeItem<ItemC, ItemD>>
>;

// This is how I want to merge instead
type MergedItems = MultipleCompositeItem<[ItemA, ItemB, ItemC, ItemD]>;
```

It's worth mentioning that in my components, `GlobalItem` should always be available, and the other `Item`s would be used as needed.

---

Finally, my question is: **Is there a way to create this `MultipleCompositeItem` type where I wouldn't have to check for each position of the array by myself? But rather check it dinamically based on how many `Item`s I provide to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual (albeit not trivial) solution for such case is to use a recursive type with tuple shifting/popping (so that it consumes the tuple elements until none are left):

```
type MultipleCompositeItem<Items extends readonly LibItem[]> =
  Items["length"] extends 1 // Special case when there is only 1 item left
  ? Items[0] // No composition needed for a single item
  : Items extends [unknown, ...infer Rest] // Shift the 1st item
    ? Rest extends readonly LibItem[] // Unfortunately we need to re-narrow the type of Rest...
      ? LibCompositeItem<Items[0], MultipleCompositeItem<Rest>> // Compose the first item with the rest
      : never // Should really never occur, because Items is already constrained
    : never // Covers case when Items has NO elements

// This is how I want to merge instead
type MergedItems = MultipleCompositeItem<[ItemA, ItemB, ItemC, ItemD]>;
//   ^? { propA: string; } & LibItem & { propB: string; } & { propC: string; } & { propD: string; }
type MergedItemsSingle = MultipleCompositeItem<[ItemA]>;
//   ^? { propA: string; } & LibItem
type MergedItemsNone = MultipleCompositeItem<[]>;
//   ^? never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwOwOQBdoAt4HMCmomqwM45ICeADoQFCkWgAyAlgEbhJYC2oAvKAN6jY4WAE4MoABWEB7MgC5QBJKLgZQAXwDc1cjkZMAwlPZkpBBm1YcAPAEFQWAB5s4AEwL1ml9gBpQAIXsnLFd3PS8APm5QOwAyfw1QEFAAFVQGd3TQAHcYElB2KWEcKCMyABtHUAY4XHxQIpgyquMK9mCkGCQGKThKbVoAcTKpJkavKP4MYdGyyRl5RWVVNVA4sLZ2LRocLzsefjJpMhsFpWrl1Y8WDa2dCA2A-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)

Comment: Wow, you wrote some beautiful typescript there! I had to make some tweaks to always include the `GlobalItem` in the resulting merged type, but it works perfectly! Thank you for the answer :D